# Concern related to android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app in which the user adds time and notes, and will display in a list. When i am trying to get entered data from user in `onActivityResult`, I faced a problem. Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String notes = data.getStringExtra("notes");
            String time = data.getStringExtra("time");

            TimeTrackerAdapter.TimeRecord(new TimeRecord(time, notes));
            TimeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code from where i am trying to get data:

```
public void onSave(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final EditText timeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    intent.putExtra("time", timeView.getText().toString());

    EditText notesView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes_view);
    intent.putExtra("notes", notesView.getText().toString());

    this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: post your error please

Comment: i faced error in these two lines TimeTrackerAdapter.TimeRecord(new TimeRecord(time, notes));
       TimeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: first in TimeRecord and second in TimeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You need to use object of `TimeTrackerAdapter`. Not the class name.

Comment: it says cannot make a static reference to non static method

Comment: how i create it i am new in java

Comment: @muhammadarslan: I think you have an object of `TimeTrackerAdapter` already in that class (adapter that you are using).

Comment: Post more code for your `Activity` and your code for `TimeTrackerAdapter` - you need a "new" statement to create the object

Comment: yes i have an object

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.times_list);
        
        TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter = new TimeTrackerAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
    }

Comment: use `timeTrackerAdapter.TimeRecord(new TimeRecord(time, notes));` and `timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: this is also not work for me

Comment: @muhammadarslan: Where are you passing the data to the class ? I'm not seeing any TimeRecord method in your adapter class.

Comment: what i can do for it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your actual instance of the TimeTrackerAdapter in your code that you created. Then you add your new TimeRecord to the array you have stored in the TimeTrackerAdapter class through your instance of the adapter as well. Then notify the listview for a dataSetchange

```
timeTrackerAdapter.times.add(new TimeRecord(time, notes));
timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Change your constructor to the TimeTrackerAdapter Class to this.

```
    public TimeTrackerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<TimeRecord> times) 
    { 
         super(context, textViewResourceId, times);
         this.times=times
    }
```

and when you create the timeTrackerAdapter, call it like this

```
timeTrackerAdapter= new TimeTrackerAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.time_list_item,[The ArrayList of TimeRecords that is set before populating the listView]);
```

if you are in the the Activity class, then change getActivity() to: this instead

```
timeTrackerAdapter= new TimeTrackerAdapter(this,R.layout.time_list_item,[The ArrayList of TimeRecords that is set before populating the listView]);
```

Comment: not work for me all errors are removed but could not display anyhing

Comment: also i think you need some stuff for your constructor on the adapter. I'll add that in my answer in a second

Comment: check out this                                                                                      public class TimeRecord extends Activity {
 
 private String time;
 private String notes;
 
 public TimeRecord(String time, String notes) 
 {
   this.time = time;
   this.notes = notes;
 }

Comment: your Object class for TimeRecord shouldn't be the problem as long as it has values and is in an array. check my updates and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Was that the problem or did it still fail?